# Tagged picture not appearing on my feed despite correct settings

Tags: facebook

On Facebook, I've recently been tagged in two posts by friends. Usually I have to review these to be added to my timeline/page. No settings have been changed but the last 2 didn't ask for a review and haven't been shared to my page. I've reset my settings but I'm missing something.

I've also gone to the review section and the posts aren't even showing in there.

Please could someone help?